# Safari doesn't allow AJAX Requests after form submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, yui

I am writing a Javascript based upload progress meter. I want to use the standard multipart submit method (rather than submitting the file in an iframe). During the submit, I send ajax requests that return the % complete of the upload and then update the progress meter accordingly.

This all works smoothly in FireFox & IE. However, Safari seems prevent the completion of ajax requests after the main form has been submitted.  In the debugger, I can see the request headers, but it appears as though the response is never received.

Anyone aware of this, or how to get around it?

Comment: Please post some code, maybe there's a way to workaround the problem

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is how Safari and any browser based on WebKit (i.e. Google Chrome) behave.  I recently ran into this on a file upload progress meter also.  I ended up using the same technique seen at http://drogomir.com/blog/2008/6/30/upload-progress-script-with-safari-support to get the ajax to work.  In my case, I didn't want to change the look of my application to the one Drogomir uses, but the technique itself worked.  Essentially, the solution is to create a hidden iframe only in Safari that loads jQuery and your AJAX script.  Then, the top frame calls a function in that frame on form submit.  All other browsers still work the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

This is a WebKit bug. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23933

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an iframe to submit your form to? I'm guessing that once the form is submitted, the page enters a state where no more modifications to the DOM can be made.

Check a tutorial such as [this one](http://blog.joshuaeichorn.com/archives/2006/03/14/php-ajax-file-upload-progress-meter-updates/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This actually sounds like correct behaviour to me - and im surprised that firefox and IE behave otherwise.

It is akin to you attempting to leave a page and the page still interacting with you - sounds naughty!

i can see why this would be of benefit - but I would hope it only the case if you are performing a POST to the uri you are currently accessing, or at worst same-domain.